# Batch files - checking arguments

Tags: batch-file

I had to create three batch files. two would be to configure the environment variables and the other would run an example.

Then I have confvarsC.bat (C + + environment variables)and confvarsJ.bat (Java environment variables). 
And then I created the executePortico.bat that does the following: tests the java_home the rti_home and calls the file of environment variables.
But I need that if the person typing "c" should call the confvarsC.bat and run the examples in C + +, if the person type "j" should call the confvarsJ.bat and run the Java examples.

See that i did:

```
@echo off

rem ###########################
rem # implementation/version  #
rem ###########################

set IMP=portico

rem ################################
rem # check command line arguments #
rem ################################
:checkargs
if "%0" == "" goto usage
if "%1" == "" goto usage


rem #######################
rem # test for JAVA_HOME  #
rem #######################
if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto nojava
goto rtihometest

:nojava
echo ERROR Your JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set!
goto usage

rem #######################
rem # test for RTI_HOME   #
rem #######################
:rtihometest

if "%0" == "c" goto execC
if "%0" == "j" goto execJ
goto finish

:execC
call C:\Arquivos de programas\Portico\portico-1.0.2\etc\confvarsC.bat
if not "%RTI_HOME%" == "" goto execute

:execJ
call C:\Arquivos de programas\Portico\portico-1.0.2\etc\confvarsJ.bat
if not "%RTI_HOME%" == "" goto execute


############################################
### (target) execute #######################
############################################
:execute
SHIFT
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\client;%RTI_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set RTI_FEDDIR=C:\Arquivos de programas\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13
set EXEC = "C:\Arquivos de programas\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13"

if "%0" == "m" goto exec1

:exec1
echo %EXEC%%1%IMP%.exe
pause
%EXEC%%1%IMP%.exe %2
goto finish

:usage
echo usage: executePortico.bat [model] [nome modelo]
goto err

:err
echo Terminated - Error
goto end

:finish
echo Terminated - Normal

:end
```

---

I did this, see my code please:
But i have a problem, when I try to run a Java example, he does not enter the executeJava, he always goes into executeC.

See in my commmand prompt:

C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\exec>executePortico.bat java-hla13
Por favor escolha a linguagem (J)ava or (C)++: j
C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\java-hla13.exe
Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
'"C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\java-hla13.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Terminated - Normal

And the Java examples are in directory: C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\java\hla13

```
@echo off

rem ###########################
rem # implementation/version  #
rem ###########################


rem ################################
rem # check command line arguments #
rem ################################
:checkargs


if "%0"=="" goto usage
if "%1"=="" goto usage

set /p language=Por favor escolha a linguagem (J)ava or (C)++: 

if %language%=="C" goto execC
if %language%=="J" goto execJ



rem #######################
rem # test for JAVA_HOME  #
rem #######################
if "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" goto nojava
goto rtihometest

:nojava
echo ERROR Your JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set!

goto usage



rem #######################
rem # test for RTI_HOME   #
rem #######################
:rtihometest


echo EU aqui no executeC

:execC
call C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\etc\confvarsC.bat
if "%RTI_HOME%"=="" goto nortihome
if not "%RTI_HOME%"=="" goto executeC


:execJ
call C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\etc\confvarsJ.bat
if "%RTI_HOME%"=="" goto nortihome 
if not "%RTI_HOME%"=="" goto executeJava


:nortihome
echo ERROR Your JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set!
goto usage


################################################
### (target) execute C++ #######################
################################################
:executeC

set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\client;%RTI_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set RTI_FEDDIR=C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13
set EXEC=C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\cpp\cpp13\

echo %EXEC%%1.exe
pause
"%EXEC%%1.exe"

goto finish


#################################################
### (target) execute Java #######################
#################################################
:executeJava

set PATH=PATH=%RTI_HOME%\include\ng6;%RTI_HOME%\lib;%RTI_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set ClassPath=%RTI_HOME%\lib\portico.jar
set RTI_FEDDIR=C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\java\hla13
set EXECUTA=C:\Portico\portico-1.0.2\examples\java\hla13\


echo %EXECUTA%java-hla13.jar
pause
"%EXECUTA%java-hla13.jar"

goto finish



:usage


echo usage: executePortico.bat [model] [nome modelo]
goto err

:err
echo Terminated - Error
goto end

:finish
echo Terminated - Normal

:end
```

Answer (score 2):

in your `:checkargs`, **%0** will always have something in - that is the name of the batch file - so there is no need to test that value

**%1** is the first parameter, so in `:rtihometest` you need to compare **%1** with c or j, not **%0**

in `:execC`, you do not jump anywhere after the second test, so `:execJ` will be executed too.

in `:execJ`, you do not jump anywhere after the second test, so `:execute` will be executed regardless of the result of the test.

Answer (score 0):

First, **%0 is the name of the file, %1 is the first argument.**

Then, please add `:exit` at the end, and when the program needs to exit, type `goto exit`.

Example of a proper argument-checking batch file:

```
@echo off
set param=%1
set var1=1
set var2=2

if [%1]==[] goto noparam
if %param%==%var1% goto isvar1
if %param%==%var2% goto isvar2
goto unknown

:isvar1
echo The parameter is 1.
goto exit

:isvar2
echo The parameter is 2.
goto exit

:noparam
echo No parameter.
goto exit

:unknown
echo Unknown parameter - %param%.
:exit
```

Here are various test cases (here the file is named `numbers`):

```
C:\Users\user\Documents>numbers
No parameter.

C:\Users\user\Documents>numbers 1
The parameter is 1.

C:\Users\user\Documents>numbers 2
The parameter is 2.

C:\Users\user\Documents>numbers foo
Unknown parameter - foo.
```